# Effective masses of GaAs-lattice-matched InGaAsP, using k.p method or else

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

For numerical simulations, I need the effective masses of electrons, light & heavy holes, and split-off carriers, in GaAs-lm InGaAsP.  Alternatively, I am considering using the k.p method to estimate them, but couldn't find information on the appropriate Luttinger parameters. Are you aware of any database where the masses or the Luttinger parameter are available? How would you suggest I could proceed? Are there any other relatively simple methods to compute them (DFT or else) ?

Best,

Comment: Something very similar is implemented in solcore https://github.com/qpv-research-group/solcore5/blob/develop/examples/kp_fit_effective_masses.py